# Difference between v-text and v-load in Vue.js when hiding {{ Mustache }}?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When dealing with "flash of uncompiled content" in Vue, the split seconds (or more) where the page is loading and you see the `{{ Mustache }}`, I've seen people using both [v-text](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-text) and [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak).

With v-text, the documentation says:

> Updates the element’s `textContent`. If you need to update the part of
> `textContent`, you should use `{{ Mustache }}` interpolations.

With v-cloak:

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue
> instance finishes compilation. Combined with CSS rules such as
> `[v-cloak] { display: none }`, this directive can be used to hide
> un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready.

So it sounds like if I don't need to update the `textContent`, I can use either to achieve the same result. Besides that, what is the difference between `v-text` and `v-cloak`? And is one better than another when it comes to hiding `{{ Mustache }}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`v-text` is for setting the entire textNode of an element equal to some value. It's intended to be used in place of `{{}}` when you are wanting to affect all of the text content. `v-cloak` is however meant for hiding an element until compilation is complete.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you!